# I caught error when i tried start jenkins on custom port

Tags: java, jenkins

My system is Linux mint 18.3. Java version "1.8.0_161". When i start jenkins by using command "java -jar jenkins.war" -All went right. When i start jenkins inside tomcat -All went right. But when i tried to start jenkins by using command "java -jar jenkins.war -- httpPort=9090" i got error. Could you help me find reason?

---

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:309)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized option: --
        at winstone.cmdline.CmdLineParser.parse(CmdLineParser.java:53)
        at winstone.Launcher.getArgsFromCommandLine(Launcher.java:363)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:334)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be because of the space between `--` and `httpPort`?

Comment: Thanks a lot . You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space between `--` and `httpPort`. Just change it to be something like this:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

Comment: Nice to hear that!